# Add a column in the output with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to get a fifth column with my current code ?
Actually the output looks like that when I add the Column5:

```
Column1 : infra-1
Column2 : infra-852
Column3 : infra-12
Column4 : infra-99
Column5 : infra-25
```

The output without Column5:

```
Column1  Column2   Column3   Column4 
-------  -------   -------   ------- 
infra-1  infra-852 infra-12  infra-99
```

I use `$csv | Select-Object Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4`  to display it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "issue" you are facing is, that powershell start to show results in `list-format`, at 5 properties or more. You could either stop at 4 properties (don't think this will help you) or output via `Format-Table`:

```
$csv | Select-Object Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4 | Format-Table
```

You might need to use some of the switches (e.g. `-Wrap`)

**update**

Beware that the results you produce are only worth displaying. They loose their properties as powershell objects and you cannot use methods or properties the may have had before!